# What is wrong with this function, and how can I make it work?

Tags: python, function

```
def func(sentence):
    sumn = sentence.split()
    if len(sumn) >= 5:
        return sumn


plswork = func("me name goooose")
print(plswork)
```

When I use this if statement with a list outside of a function, it returns the element in the list that is 5 characters or greater. When applied to this function, it fails.

Essentially I am trying to create a function that identifies elements of a certain length, reverses these specific elements, and prints the new list. Though, I have not yet gotten to the reverse portion of my function yet.

Comment: That function returns a list of the words in the sentence, if the sentence is at least five words long. Is that *not* what you wanted?

Comment: When you `.split()`, it turns into a list.  Currently you're checking the length of the entire list, in this case 3.  Nothing is wrong with the function - it's working as-is (technically). Try `func("me name gooose maverick iceman")` and it'll return `5`...

Comment: So what I wanted to do was take in a string. Convert string to list. Then use len to check each element of list for elements with 5 or more characters. When I call the function, I want it to print the goose word since it is more than 5 characters. Or, if I have multiple words with 5 or more characters print those as well.

Comment: Do you know how I can individually check each element of the list instead of checking the entire list? I need to check specific elements in the list

Comment: That's **not** the logic you've written. Maybe research "Python iterate over list" or "Python apply to every item in list". A good structured tutorial should cover basic ideas like this: https://sopython.com/wiki/What_tutorial_should_I_read%3F

Comment: Have a look into using a `for` loop over the list elements.

Comment: As pointed out above, your function just returns the number of words if the list itself is bigger than 5. To return the words with more than 5 characters, you need to loop over the words in the result of split() and collect the ones that have more than 5 characters.

Comment: That makes sense. That is why it worked when I tried it outside of my function. I parsed the list with a for loop but did not think the for loop was necessary in the function. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you want:

```
def func(sentence):
    sumn = sentence.split()
    for i in sumn:
        if len(i) >= 5:
            print(i)
    
func("me name goooose")
```

Comment: You can also use a list comprehension: [w for w in "me name goooose".split() if len(w) >= 5]

Comment: Thank you so much. In the code you have written you declare i right in the loop.  For future reference, variables can be declared mid for loop?

Comment: i is not a variable, it's alive only inside the loop

Comment: Please accept the answer, if it solves your problem
Thanks

Comment: @archer `i` is both a variable *and* "alive" outside the loop (although only briefly, as the function then ends).

Comment: Yeah, you are right, i mean it is not a common variable, it is just temporary, to facilitate the funcionality of the loop and the function. Especially when it is used inside a function it is completely dead outside it (if the loop was outside the function it would just keep the last value of the loop and it is too rarely used somewhere else)